# Monotouch WCF call crashes with SIGILL error on 10th attempt

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, xamarin.ios

Using latest monotouch(4.0.3) we have WCF services that are called. After performing the call the 10th attempt crashes. I have created a test program that calls simple WCF call to see if service is up. Responds with an OK message. On 10th call it fails. Tried Server config settings, Close, Dispose on client still same results. Sample Test code segment below:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();


        mailButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) =>
        {

        BasicHttpBinding BindType = new BasicHttpBinding();
        BindType.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,15);

        EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(@"http://myservice.mydomain.com/MyBusServiceBusService/MFService.svc/BaseService");
        BaseServiceClient MFService = new BaseServiceClient(BindType, ep);
        MFService.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
        MFService.BaseServiceTestCompleted += delegate(object sender, BaseServiceTestCompletedEventArgs ex) 
          {
              UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView();
              alert.Title = "Base Service Test";
              alert.AddButton("Ok");
              ++timesThrough;
              alert.Message = ex.Result + " Times=" + timesThrough.ToString();;
              alert.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{alert.Show();  });
              var clientObject = sender as BaseServiceClient;
                if (clientObject != null && clientObject.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                       (clientObject.ChannelFactory).Close();
                     (clientObject).Close();
                      ((IDisposable)clientObject).Dispose();
                     clientObject = null;
                }
              if (MFService != null)
                 {

                    (MFService.ChannelFactory).Close();
                     (MFService).Close();
                      ((IDisposable)MFService).Dispose();
                     MFService = null;
                 }

             GC.Collect();



        };

        try
        {
          MFService.BaseServiceTestAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView();
          alert.Title = "Base Service Test";
          alert.AddButton("Ok");

          alert.Message = ex.Message ;
          alert.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{alert.Show();});
          MFService = null;
          GC.Collect();
        }



        };
    }
```

Comment: What is the error when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the latest MonoTouch (4.1 beta). The 4.2 (stable) release should be available soon.